# how to use swiper slider with jquery tabs?

Tags: jquery, tabs, slider, swiper.js

I am trying to use idangero swiper with jquery tabs i am getting all the result i want except pagination.slider pagination showing only one bullet.It work fine when use with single tab but i don't know how to apply swiper when two or more tabs are required.here is my code and jsfiddle links for eg.http://jsfiddle.net/Rzeiwald/wunw9enL/3/ -
http://jsfiddle.net/Rzeiwald/m61qfck1/
Thank you for your time
HTML

```
        <div class="panel" style="background : transparent; border: none;">
        <div id="tabs-centre"  style="background : transparent;margin-left:5px;border: none;">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-centre-1">op</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-centre-2">oop</a></li>
        </ul>


        <div id="tabs-centre-1">
        <!-- Swiper -->
        <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">

        <div class="swiper-slide roundbox">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide roundbox">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide roundbox">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide roundbox">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide roundbox">
        </div>


        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination" ></div>
         <!-- Add Arrows -->
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        </div><!--Swiper Ends-->
        </div><!-- End: Tabs1 -->

        <div id="tabs-centre-2">
        <!-- Swiper -->
        <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">

        <div class="swiper-slide roundbox">
        </div>


        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination" ></div>
         <!-- Add Arrows -->
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        </div><!--Swiper Ends-->
        </div><!-- End: Tabs2 -->

        </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    slidesPerView: 3,
    centeredSlides: false,
    paginationClickable: true,
    autoplay: 2500,
    spaceBetween: 15,
});
```

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your time http://jsfiddle.net/Rzeiwald/wunw9enL/3/ works fine with  one tab but when i put second tabs swiper does not load properly http://jsfiddle.net/Rzeiwald/m61qfck1/ i want to use swiper with three tabs

Comment: I'm sorry to replay late. Check your answer.

Answer (score 0):

1- According to [swiper initialization](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/get-started/#.Vh9yZH4rKUl), You must call your script inside `$(document).ready` or end of `body` or inside `window.onload`.

2- You have to call `.tabs()` after swiper. I think swiper try to apply on elements which are hidden or don't have width/height and etc.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m61qfck1/2/)

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        slidesPerView: 3,
        centeredSlides: false,
        paginationClickable: true,
        autoplay: 2500,
        spaceBetween: 15,
    });
    $('#tabs').tabs();
});
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! Thank you so much!! i was trying to solve this from about two weeks! :D you are a savior