# Swiper slider breaks on tabs

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs, swiper.js

Hello using Swiper slider by [slider home page](http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WUAb0Ma1sd8)

Here is the website home page it is setup on.
[MY SITE WITH SWIPER SLIDER](http://www51.myfantasyleague.com/2017/home/61106#0)

The Code
inner html

```
       <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dagrafixdesigns.com/Images/2008/DA_2017/DA_RSkin/swiper.min.css">



    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide"><picture><img src="//dagrafixdesigns.com/Images/2008/DA_2017/DA_RSkin/Slider/Slide1.png"></picture></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><picture><img src="//dagrafixdesigns.com/Images/2008/DA_2017/DA_RSkin/Slider/Slide2.png"></picture></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><report><module name="LIVESCORING_SUMMARY"/></report></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><picture><img src="//dagrafixdesigns.com/Images/2008/DA_2017/DA_RSkin/Slider/Slide3.png"></picture></div>
            <div class="swiper-slide"><report><module name="OWNER_ACTIVITY"/></report></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>



    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
        loop: true,
        keyboardControl: true,
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 10,
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next-icon',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev-icon',
        autoplay:3000,
        speed:1000,
        grabCursor:true,
        roundLengths: true,
                effect: 'fade',
                fade: {
                  crossFade:true
                }
    });
});

</script>
```

Website loads and slide works nicely, however if you click the TABS GAMEDAY, MY TEAM, MISC, and scroll up or down on any of these tabs, then click back to the HOME TAB the slider is struck frozen.

I have read some reports on tabs and swiper and have tried to mod the script with tabs, but I cant seem to get it to work.

[stack flow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126141/how-to-use-swiper-slider-with-jquery-tabs)

Would like to keep my script code and see why the tabs call out wont work for me. I replaced the #tabs with #homepagetabs per my site tabs element call, still don't work.

Thank you!

Comment: wrap your swiper code in a function, call it on doc ready and any time the home tab is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var swiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', { 
                           loop: true, 
                           keyboardControl: true, 
                           pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
                           paginationClickable: true, 
                           spaceBetween: 10, 
                           nextButton: '.swiper-button-next-icon',
                           prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev-icon',
                           autoplay:3000,
                           speed:1000,
                           grabCursor:true,
                           roundLengths: true,
                           effect: 'fade',
                           fade: { 
                             crossFade:true 
                           }
                          }                                    
                        });

    $("#tab0").click(function(){
            var swiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', { 
                           loop: true, 
                           keyboardControl: true, 
                           pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
                           paginationClickable: true, 
                           spaceBetween: 10, 
                           nextButton: '.swiper-button-next-icon',
                           prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev-icon',
                           autoplay:3000,
                           speed:1000,
                           grabCursor:true,
                           roundLengths: true,
                           effect: 'fade',
                           fade: { 
                             crossFade:true 
                           }                                    
                          }
                        });
});
```

Since this appears to have resolved the Swiper functionality issues, you can try this to clean it up again:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    initSwiper(); 
    $("#tab0").click(function(){ 
        initSwiper();
    });
});

function initSwiper(){
    var swiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', { 
                           loop: true, 
                           keyboardControl: true, 
                           pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
                           paginationClickable: true, 
                           spaceBetween: 10, 
                           nextButton: '.swiper-button-next-icon',
                           prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev-icon',
                           autoplay:3000,
                           speed:1000,
                           grabCursor:true,
                           roundLengths: true,
                           effect: 'fade',
                           fade: { 
                             crossFade:true 
                           }                                    
                          }
                        });
}
```

Comment: $( document ).ready(function() {
 var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
  loop: true,
  keyboardControl: true,
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
  paginationClickable: true,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next-icon',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev-icon',
  autoplay:3000,
  speed:1000,
  grabCursor:true,
  roundLengths: true,
                effect: 'fade',
                fade: {
                  crossFade:true
                }
 });
});                                 This is my code, can you post final mark up and I will try to paste it

Comment: sorry for the LIFE of me, I tried to post my code on reply so it is formatted and with no menu like above , I cant seem to get it working....frustrating! ... I highlighted the code and do the ctrl+k and it jumped to a entirely new page  Is there a editor for replys?

Comment: No editor for replies. I think I understood, you wanted me to update the swiper code in my answer from your reply? Right?

Comment: yes sir I need my script file posted above in grey and reply post, with your additions sent back to me to re-paste on my site and test please......I was stating I was trying to reply back to you and do my code again formatted neatly in gray background (so its easy to read etc) but on replys to post....you get no full editor like you do a new post...so I cant figure it out and just posted it anyway LOL....  but yeah please resend my current script with your additions and let me try to see if it works

Comment: Just copy my answer to your site for testing and replace the swiper definition. I can't test it for you.

Comment: Yes I seen you made that change and I pasted it, however now the slider DOES not work....see site url

Comment: Looks like you're missing a ) somewhere

Comment: at the very top post is my original code, I though so also and at the bottom added   );    that behind your code but still don't work..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146567/discussion-between-mjw-and-da-g-guru).

Comment: Was checking back in....let me know if this is still being worked on or I guess the public can peek in also Thx

Comment: Did you check the chat? I updated the order of the parameters in my answer above. I'll check back when I have some time today.

Comment: I assume you are stuck on this as I didn't see any new code to try?

Comment: look in the chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146792/discussion-between-da-g-guru-and-mjw).

Comment: ALl I see is this   in the chat room       $(document).ready( initSwiper(); $("#tab0").click("initSwiper()"); )}; function initSwiper() { var swiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', { loop: true, keyboardControl: true, pagination...

Comment: Your code got cut off it looks like man... can you repost the entire string please

Comment: It isn't cut off, as I said, I reordered the parameter list in my answer above. It isn't the same. I moved the fade args up in the list.

Comment: Have you looked at the site script then? Because I added what you posted to the script and I pasted this also on the chat room just now, you can see the slider is not even sliding now.?

Comment: Please if you can, post in the chat room at the bottom your entire string of code, I will try to see if it is the same or not and give it another try...I think this just might be a busted idea, I hope we can get it working but I am losing faith lol

Comment: Please give the updates above a try. What i've changed is more or less removing the function call used to bind to the click event of your Home tab and replacing it with the full block used to init the Swiper. This also reverts your original doc ready back so it should work again.

Comment: coded added...seems to long to me, so I added the entire thing and also split it in half to just see, both ways the slider does not work still now.... I think this is a dead issue now, seems to difficult to get this to work in tabs I feel. I should move on to a different slider all together at this point. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Your call, what I would do is revert your swiper code to the original where it was working. Then once that works, duplicate the swiper definition in the click handler for your tab. It looks like the console was reporting issues with swiper definitions. I added a couple closing } to the above argument lists.

Comment: That fixes it on my end when I add the } as shown above in my console.

Comment: I added the cleaned up code from above to the site, unfortunately the slider is still not working. Stupid swiper

Comment: It definitely works on my end. Did you first try the longer block without initSwiper?

Comment: I have tried this code everyway around and still no luck outside of my original posted code where the slider does work, just not in tabs.   Now i tried your latest code fix, and the slider doesnt move, you can see the code on the site still, but here it is in a script tag   LISTED ON THE CHAT ROOM since it is to long here

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.target // newly activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
   YourSlideFunction();
})
```